How can I add a key/value to a sub-object in a postgres jsonb column
I have a table with a jsonb column containing data like:
{
    "key_a": "value",
    "key_b": {
        "_reference": "reference to remote object 1"
    },
    "key_c": {
        "key_d": {
            "_reference": "reference to remote object 2"
        }
    }
}

In a trigger when that jsonb column is updated, I need to find any part of the object (at any level, under any key) containing a key "_reference", look up the referenced remote object from a different record in the table, and import its data, resulting in an object like:
{
    "key_a": "value",
    "key_b": {
        "_reference": "reference to remote object 1",
        "remote_key": "remote value from object 2"
    },
    "key_c": {
        "key_d": {
            "_reference": "reference to remote object 2",
            "remote_key": "remote value from object 2"
        }
    }
}

The reason for this is primarily performance; the updates happen rarely, while the lookups happen all the time, and I'd like them to be snappy.
Any ideas for how to do this in postgres? My current thought is to just make a self-referencing function that searches the entire object and returns the path arrays for any location in the object that contains the "_reference" key, but I'm wondering if there's any faster/easier/native-er way to go about it.

Yes, a recursive function should be the most straightforward way to solve this. There might be alternatives, but I wouldn't recommend them.
